# Errors when importing phonegap project to eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, phonegap-build

I created a phonegap project usin command line interface and successfully import into eclipse and after successful import getting below error :  [image]

Comment: You are importing the resulting Android project right? You have to import CordovaLib project too in order to get it working. You can find it in platforms/android/CordovaLib, import it to eclipse too.

Comment: did not work for me after importing CordovaLib in Eclipse.

Comment: Didnt told you before but, after you import it you have to link it to your cordova/phonegap project, go to your android project/properties/Android and in the 'Library' section add it, if when you click 'Add' dont see the project, just go to the same place but in the CordovaLib Project add check 'Is Library' , then try again. I hope this fix it.

Comment: clicking on 'Add' not getting the project, I did same for CordovaLib Project but there is no option for checking 'Is Library'.

Comment: Dont you have this option? http://i.imgur.com/brcAMlP.png?1